# Front-end editing in Rails by css designer without using rails eco-system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, frontend

My app has a Ruby on Rails back-end (using git and heroku), and a front-end designer (css/jquery) just asked if he could work on the code without install rails (i.e. downloading the code from git, and just ftp'ing it to heroku).

It does not seem like it is possible to FTP to heroku.  Is there some other way that front-end developers can interact with rails without having to install rails on their own?

Thank you!

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide a sample of static html pages generated thanks to the actual application together with the css & js files. The only point missing is the ajax processes then.

Comment: interesting.  so you'd just send what the html of the generated pages, then input those html / css changes yourself?

Comment: That is more a workaround than a real solution, I agree. But unless you want your designer to learn the html.erb code, I don't see any other solution. If you find any, keep me posted: I'm interested ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If he only needs to edit files (css, js, ...), he can just pull your code from git (in your case maintained by Heroku, I guess) and push back.
But, I guess he'll also want to see how his changes look like, and for that he needs to run the rails server.
Check the Heroku toolbelt (or something similar to that), it's supposed to be easy to install and allows you to checkout code from heroku and run the server. I've never used that but think I've heard about it once.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for him to do it without installing rails.  He will need to use git however to push to heroku as it doesn't support ftp, partly because various processes are tied into the git pushes.

I want to be clear though:  Even with using git, I strongly recommend against it.  Rails does a lot of processing around its view files, layouts, css, js, etc. and removing the ability to see what they look like as served up by the actual app is inviting problems.

One option you might consider is setting up the rails environment for the designer so that they don't have to learn much and they can be at the 'push a button or two' level.

Another option is that you basically become the 'master' and shuttle the files to and from the server and check them locally.  This is even more inefficient but of course could suit some bureaucracies or organizations.